# I need to make two divs alternate with display "block" and "none"

Tags: javascript

The problem is that my blocks are not changing their properties, but `console.log()` works properly. What is wrong?

Here's my code:

```
var imageContainer = document.querySelector('.image-container'); // My first div
var imageContainerSecond = document.querySelector('.image-container-second'); // My second div

setInterval(function() { // i am using set interval to call this function every 2 seconds

  if (imageContainer.style.display === 'block') { // I checking if my div has property of 'block'
    imageContainerSecond.style.display = 'none'; // if it block, another div has to become 'none'
    console.log('error');
  } else(imageContainerSecond.style.display === 'none') { // here opposite logic
    imageContainer.style.display = 'block';
    console.log('ok');
  }
}, 2000); // my interval
```

Comment: else(imageContainerSecond.style.display = 'none' I think you mean. 
else if(imageContainerSecond.style.display == 'none')

Comment: You used the correct number of equals in the first condition, `===`. For the else, see [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#Using_else_if).

Comment: I need to alternate visibility of this blocks by changing "display" property. i.e, if one block is display 'none', other has to be display 'block'

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `(imageContainerSecond.style.display = 'none')` Remember It's an `else`.

Your `image-container` `div` needs to start with `style="display: block;"`:

```
<div class="image-container" style="display: block;">One</div>
```

In every condition you need to set the proper styles.

Something like this:

```js
var imageContainer = document.querySelector('.image-container');
var imageContainerSecond = document.querySelector('.image-container-second');

setInterval(function() {
  if (imageContainer.style.display === 'block') {
    imageContainer.style.display = 'none';
    imageContainerSecond.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    imageContainer.style.display = 'block';
    imageContainerSecond.style.display = 'none';
  }
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div class="image-container" style="display: block;">One</div>
<div class="image-container-second">Two</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would i like to suggest a more stable method, so you could add however much "divs". The basic gist of the code is to make a function that iterates from the list obtained. The list consists of the "screen-content" that wants to be alternatively be shown.

```js
const divs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".screen-content"));
    const previousBtn = document.getElementById("previous-btn");
    const nextBtn = document.getElementById("next-btn");
    
    previousBtn.addEventListener("click", showPreviousContent);
    nextBtn.addEventListener("click", showNextContent);
    
    divs.forEach((div, index) => {
      if (index !== 0) {
        div.classList.add("hide");
      }
    });
    
    let currentIndex = 0;
    divs[currentIndex].classList.remove("hide");
    
    function showPreviousContent() {
        divs[currentIndex].classList.add("hide");
        currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + divs.length) % divs.length;
        divs[currentIndex].classList.remove("hide");
    }
    
    function showNextContent() {
        divs[currentIndex].classList.add("hide");
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % divs.length;
        divs[currentIndex].classList.remove("hide");
    }
```

```css
.hide{
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="screen-content">This is a content</div>
    <div class="screen-content">This is another content</div>
    <button id="previous-btn" style="height:50px; width:50px"></button>
    <button id="next-btn" style="height:50px; width:50px"></button>
```